# Why is the RuntimeDirectory is not created by user service startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, xdg

when I start "myApplication-myInstance.service" as a user, the `RuntimeDirectory` (see `man systemd.exec`) is not created :

```bash
$ systemctl --user cat myApplication-myInstance.service | grep RuntimeDirectory=
RuntimeDirectory=myApplication
$ systemctl --user list-unit-files myApplication-myInstance.service
UNIT FILE                    STATE   VENDOR PRESET
myApplication-myInstance.service enabled enabled

1 unit files listed.
$ ls /run/user/$UID/ | grep myApplication
$
```

EDIT0 : My service is active but exited maybe because the startup script uses a `nohup` :

```bash
$ systemctl --user status myApplication-myInstance.service | grep "Active"
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-03-31 11:54:59 CEST; 6h ago
$ systemctl --user cat myApplication-myInstance.service | grep -A3 ^.Service
[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
RuntimeDirectory=myApplication
$ echo $UID
1002
$
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Is `RuntimeDirectory=` under `[Service]`? Is `myApplication-myInstance.service` started (instead of just enabled)? Is `$UID` really set to anything at all?

Comment: @TomYan Please see my EDIT0. Do I need to set the `RuntimeDirectoryPreserve` parameter to `Yes` ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem here (version 253.2). Even without `RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=yes` the `RuntimeDirectory=` gets created and remain until I explicity stop the service (which has `ExecStart=/usr/bin/true` and `RemainAfterExit=yes`) with `systemctl`.

Comment: @TomYan Can you try with `ExecStart=/home/your_user/start.sh`, add `nohup sleep 5m &` inside your `/home/your_user/start.sh` ?

Comment: Why do you grep for `myApplication` if you've specified that the directory name should be `filmanager`?

Comment: @user1686 Because I have forgotten to anonymise my service in this question :)